# Is "incredible" always used to describe something good?

Tags: single-word-requests

If something bad happens and it is not capable of being imagined, can I still use incredible or inconceivable?

Comment: Sure you can. Why not?

Comment: You ask two different questions - of course not answer 1 and of course answer 2.

Comment: [Looking at the dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/incredible), I am very surprised that the first definition even leans towards the literal 'unbelievable'/'inconceivable'. I have only ever thought of and used 'incredible' for 'amazing'.

Comment: How can anything actually happen that can't be imagined? (In *The Princess Bride*, the reaction of "*Inconceivable!*" wasn't used in a literal sense.)

Answer (score -1):

**Yes** (ETA- yes is to the question in the body, not to the question in the title. Thanks to @user22542 for noticing)

As you say, incredible has the sense of not capable of being imagined, but true nevertheless. Just to find an example, I put "incredible tragedy" into a search engine and found several.

Comment: [*Incredible*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/incredible) does not mean incapable of being imagined. In the sense used in the question, it means, evidence to the contrary, something that is too improbable to be believed. Also, the phrase you looked up does not use the same sense of *incredible*.

Comment: @JasonBassfordThe question was can "incredible" be used for something bad, versus only being used for something good.  It did not seem to be in the sense that "I literally don't believe you. Your story is too incredible." Rather, my interpretation of the OP's use was in the figurative sense of "This ice cream tastes incredible!" Of course it is not literally unbelievable- the ice cream is right there.  My answer was that one can also describe things that are bad using incredible figuratively as an intensifier. I am not sure how calling a tragedy that really happened incredible is different.

Comment: Follow the link I provided in my previous comment. There are two senses of *incredible*. Neither of those senses means *not capable of being imagined*. One of them means *too improbable to be believed*. So, your definition seems to be wrong. (Unless you found it in a dictionary which you haven't cited.) The *other* sense applies to *incredible tragedy* and means *extraordinary*. In your second paragraph, your first sentence starts with a definition that doesn't apply—and your second sentence uses a *different* sense altogether.

Comment: Thanks. I was using the phrasing of the OP. I took it as figurative- unable to imagine but it did happen. Such as this definition which is similar to def. 2 in your link but adds seems impossible https://www.dictionary.com/browse/incredible I apologize for the misunderstanding.